# Hover Effect on Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm in a glass case of emotion right now

I'm trying to convert the following hover effect to tailwind but not sure why it isn't working. Screenshot as follows:

[image: Hover on SVG icon]

Here is the original code using css

```
    .navbar-text button::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

and here is my tailwind setup for this icon

```
    navIcon: `rounded-full w-12 h-12 object-none border  transition-colors justify-center before:bg-white before:rounded-lg before:scale-0 before:bg-white
```

Appreciate the help

Comment: provide me a code in tailwind play.

Comment: managed to sort it out. thank you for the offering

Answer (score 0):

i think, you should know how tailwind css works, please understand basic concept [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/). basically tailwind work without we edit any css file, we edit in class on html, so if you want to know how hover work in tailwind, please come [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states). So keep learning, and happy coding.